# Is it possible to generate open api documentation from command line?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, openapi

I am trying to create a build REST API documentation using docfx based on open api (swagger) documentation of our REST API's.

I want to automatically update this documentation as part of the build process, so I need some way to generate open api documentation from command line.

I am on .net 4.7.1.

Comment: Do you generate your OpenAPI definition from source code e.g. using Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net?

Comment: right now we are using swagger-net, but are open for alternatives